# nginx rewrite url path to a param

Tags: nginx

Now I have an URL of this type:

`test.com/p/felix?order=1`

And I want to redirect it to this one:

`test.com/user/view/info?uname=felix&order=1`

and maybe there is no order param

`(test.com/p/felix to test.com/user/view/info?uname=felix)`

Now my nginx config is :

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^\/p\/(.*)\?(.*)$"){
        rewrite "^/p/(.*)?(.*)$" "/user/view/info?uname=$1&$2" break;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "^\/p\/(.*)$"){
            rewrite "^/p/(.*)$" "/user/view/info?uname=$1" break;
}
```

It works now. But I want to merge this two config into one config?

Could you tell me how to do it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the change to your question stating it works now, how about this to merge it into one:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^\/p\/(.*)\?(.*)$") {
    if ($2 = '') {
        rewrite "^/p/(.*)$" "/user/view/info?uname=$1" break;
    } else {
        rewrite "^/p/(.*)?(.*)$" "/user/view/info?uname=$1&$2" break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the url is test.com/p/felix the request_url can not match it ):